# For an undergraduate, what does it mean to publish an article in a peer-reviewed journal?

Tags: thesis, research-undergraduate, research-dissemination

I'm an undergraduate and have been able to have my thesis on curing psoriasis published in a peer-reviewed journal. Does it qualify me for anything?

Comment: This will be hard to answer if you do not tell us more about the journal.  Is it just for undergraduates?  Is it the top journal in your field?  How advised you to send it to this journal?  Is the publisher reputable?

Comment: what was your role in and contribution to the published project?

Comment: https://researchpublish.com/issue/IJTPD/Issue-1-January-2021-March-2021

Comment: This is a thesis of my own life. My purpose of asking this question is not to gain any job or a degree. I want this message to be seen by as many as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Publishing in a reputable venue is an achievement that is definitely recognized.

To potential academic grad program admission committees, it signals your readiness for a PhD degree.

To employers, it signals your willingness to dive into a project and excel in it.

To your friends, family and fellow humans, it signals that you have made the world a better, more understandable place.

Whether you *qualify* for anything really depends on how important was your contribution. You might be eligible for a scholarship or an award from your institution for example.

Comment: The posting says nothing about the journal being reputable.

Comment: Yep, all I said is conditional on that 

Answer (score 4):

This can look good on your resume, but it does depend on the quality of the journal. Even some of the worst predatory journals claim to perform peer review on their submissions. If it's a reputable journal, this surely boosts your PhD position application chances.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn’t *qualify* you for anything in the literal sense of the word “qualify”. It is merely a sort of achievement, whose value to your future studies and/or career can range anywhere between extremely positive (if you’ve discovered a revolutionary cure for psoriasis) and slightly negative (if you’ve published a garbage paper in a predatory/vanity journal).

Assuming the most normal scenario in which your paper is a legitimate paper that makes a legitimate contribution to science but is not very good or exciting (the vast majority of papers authored by undergraduates aren’t), and is published by a reputable but not very prestigious journal, what it would mainly qualify you for is a bit of respect from your peers, friends, grandmother etc; slightly improved prospects to be admitted into a good graduate program; and microscopically improved job prospects if/when you apply to non-academic jobs.

All of these are fairly minor compared to the sense of satisfaction and pride at having contributed something to the sum total of human knowledge, which is probably the biggest reward.